# MySQL Slurm db error, for no apparent reason

Tags: mysql, slurm

I am trying to access some data on a slurm MySQL database. The table `linux_job_table`  has the following columns:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| job_db_inx         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| mod_time           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| deleted            | tinyint(4)          | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| account            | tinytext            | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| admin_comment      | text                | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| array_task_str     | text                | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| array_max_tasks    | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| array_task_pending | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| constraints        | text                | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| cpus_req           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| derived_ec         | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| derived_es         | text                | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| exit_code          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| flags              | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| job_name           | tinytext            | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| id_assoc           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL       |                |
| id_array_job       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | 0          |                |
| id_array_task      | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 4294967294 |                |
| id_block           | tinytext            | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| id_job             | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL       |                |
| id_qos             | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | 0          |                |
| id_resv            | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL       |                |
| id_wckey           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL       |                |
| id_user            | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL       |                |
| id_group           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| pack_job_id        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL       |                |
| pack_job_offset    | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| kill_requid        | int(11)             | NO   |     | -1         |                |
| state_reason_prev  | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| mcs_label          | tinytext            | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| mem_req            | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| nodelist           | text                | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| nodes_alloc        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL       |                |
| node_inx           | text                | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| partition          | tinytext            | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| priority           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| state              | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| timelimit          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| time_submit        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| time_eligible      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0          |                |
| time_start         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| time_end           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0          |                |
| time_suspended     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| gres_req           | text                | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| gres_alloc         | text                | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| gres_used          | text                | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| wckey              | tinytext            | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| work_dir           | text                | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| system_comment     | text                | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
| track_steps        | tinyint(4)          | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| tres_alloc         | text                | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| tres_req           | text                | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

but when i do:

`SELECT partition from linux_job_table`

I get the following error:

```
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'partition from linux_job_table' at line 1`
```

But the same command works for all the other column headers:

```
    mysql> SELECT id_job from linux_job_table;
+--------+
| id_job |
+--------+
|      2 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anyone explain what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 3):

`PARTITION` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-P). Enclose it in backticks.

```
SELECT `partition`
       FROM linux_job_table;
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks!